# How to gracefully shut down Airflow?

Tags: airflow

We run Airflow on AWS ECS, and bundle all DAGs in a Docker Image. From time to time, we update DAGS, and deploy a new version of the Docker Image. When we do so, ECS will kill running Airflow webserver / scheduler / workers, and start new ones. We ran into issues that some DAGs, which started before the deployment, were still marked as "running" after the deployment even though their tasks have been killed by the deployment, and some externalSensor tasks were left hanging.

Is there a way to gracefully shut down Airflow ? Ideally, it could mark all running tasks as up_for_retry, and rerun them after the deployment is finished ?

Comment: Which executor are you using? You might be able to set this on the executor level instead.

Comment: using CeleryExecutor

Answer (score 0):

`docker stop <container-id/name>`

This does warm shutdown of celery workers

```
worker_1  | worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
worker_1  |
worker_1  |  -------------- celery@155afae87458 v4.1.1 (latentcall)
worker_1  | ---- **** -----
worker_1  | --- * ***  * -- Linux-4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs-x86_64-with-debian-9.5 2018-10-18 16:52:08
worker_1  | -- * - **** ---
worker_1  | - ** ---------- [config]
.......
```